# Calculate the upper sum $U_n$ and lower sum $L_n$, on a regular partition of the following interval.

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, summation

As the title says, I am trying to calculate the general formulas for the following integral.
$$\int_0^1 (5+6x^2)dx$$

I've already completed a prior integral using the advice in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1250845/calculate-the-upper-sums-un-and-lower-sums-ln-on-a-regular-partition-of-the-int/) question, but I am having trouble following the same pattern here.

I have already calculated the following components, which are hopefully correct:

$$\Delta x = \frac 1n, \quad x_i = 1+i\Delta x, \quad f(x_i) = 5+6\left(1+\frac 1n\right)^2$$

Using this I was able to get to the following point: **(1)**
\begin{equation}
\begin{split} 
\frac 1n \sum_{i=0}^n f(x_i)&=\frac 1n \sum_{i=0}^n 5+6(1+\frac 1n)^2 \\
&= \frac 1n (\sum_{i=0}^n 11 + \sum_{i=0}^n \frac {6i^2}{n^2} + \sum_{i=0}^n \frac {12i}{n})
\end{split}
\end{equation}

However my final answer after a few more steps was shown as incorrect. $$12n + \frac {6}{n^3}\frac n6 (2n+1)(n-1) + \frac{6(n+1)}{n}$$

I have obviously left out a few steps of my working, but I didn't want to bloat the question too much. Assuming my summations are correct at the end of **(1)**, I then swapped things around to get the second and third as summations of $i$ and $i^2$, and then used the relevant rules to get my answer. I can edit to add all of my working if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several mistakes in your first row of expressions. For the general expressions in my answer below, let the integral be $\int_a^b f(x)\,dx$.

Your $\Delta x$ is correct, being

$$\Delta x=\frac{b-a}n=\frac{1-0}n=\frac 1n$$

However, your $x_i$ is wrong and should be

$$x_i=a+i\Delta x=0+i\Delta x=i\Delta x$$

Your $f(x_i)$ is also wrong and should be

$$f(x_i)=5+6\left(\frac 1n\right)^2$$

Your formulas for $x_i$ and $f(x_i)$ seem to assume that the limits of integration are from $1$ to $2$, but the one you wrote is from $0$ to $1$.

Also, the limits on your summations are wrong. You have them from $0$ to $n$, but they should either be from $0$ to $n-1$ (as in the answer you linked to, which method is called the "left-side rule" or "left rectangular approximation method" or LRAM) or from $1$ to $n$ (which is the "right-side rule" or "right rectangular approximation method" or RRAM). So you want

$$\frac 1n\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} f(x_i) \qquad\text{or}\qquad \frac 1n\sum_{i=1}^{n} f(x_i)$$

Since your function is increasing, the lower sum $L_n$ will be the first summation and the upper sum $U_n$ will be the second.

Correct those errors and try again.

Comment: So with regards to the limits of the sum, since the question has it from 0 to n, can I just change it into 0 to n-1 as I go through the equation, or do I actually need to show some steps for that?

Comment: What do you mean "the question has it from 0 to n"? The integral in your question has the limits $0$ to $1$, which are different from the limits in the Riemann sum which are $0$ to $n-1$ for $L_n$ and $1$ to $n$ for $U_n$. You can just change the summation limits, since your previous ones were wrong. Make it clear whether you are finding $L_n$ or $U_n$.

Comment: Oh I see it now. Looking back I honestly have no idea why I was putting the summation from 0 to n. I somehow got it in my head that the question had me doing it. I now have my answer as 5 + ((2n+1)(n+1)/n^2), which is still wrong, but looks much better.